# why AnyVal can be converted into AnyRef at run time in Scala?

Tags: scala

The following code can be compiled without errors.

```
val a: Int = 1
val b = a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
```

That makes me confused, because Int extends AnyVal which is not a subclass but a sibling of AnyRef.

However, if an ascription is used as following:

```
val a: Int = 1
val b: AnyRef = a
```

It doesn't work.

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: AnyRef
Note: an implicit exists from scala.Int => java.lang.Integer, but
methods inherited from Object are rendered ambiguous.  This is to avoid
a blanket implicit which would convert any scala.Int to any AnyRef.
You may wish to use a type ascription: `x: java.lang.Integer`.
   val b: AnyRef = a
```

What I am understanding :

`asInstanceOf` is executed at run time, it forces compiler to believe val a is an AnyRef.
However, an ascription is at compile time, the conversion can not pass the type check, so we have a "type mismatch" error.

My questions:

1. Basically, why does the conversion work at run time ?
2. If AnyRef is considered as java.lang.Object in JVM, how about AnyVal ? Is it an Object at run time ?

   - (If yes, what's its type ? java.lang.Object ? But AnyVal is sibling of AnyRef, isn't it ?)
   - (If not, how can we use some AnyVal's subclass as Object, like Int, Double)
   - Are there some tricks played by scala compiler ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of autoboxing :

```
scala>val a: Int = 1
a: Int = 1
scala> a.getClass
res2: Class[Int] = int
scala> val b = a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
b: AnyRef = 1
scala> b.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: AnyRef] = class java.lang.Integer
```

by forcing the conversion to `AnyRef` (`java.lang.Object`) you trigger autoboxing from int to java.lang.Integer

> If AnyRef is considered as `java.lang.Object` in JVM, how about `AnyVal` ?
>   Is it an Object at run time ?

`AnyRef` is indeed an alias for `java.lang.Object`
`AnyVal` is a "virtual" type, it only exists at compile time for the sake of the type system completeness.

At run time instances extending `AnyVal` are converted to the corresponding native type (`int`, `double`, etc) except for `String` which goes to `java.lang.String` which itself extends `java.lang.Object` but has special handling in the JVM.

> But `AnyVal` is sibling of `AnyRef`, isn't it ?)

Both `AnyVal` and `AnyRef` extend the type `Any` but they don't extend each other.

> Are there some tricks played by scala compiler ?

Loads :)

For a more complete explanation of the Scala type hierarcy, I suggest you start by reading : http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html

Comment: Small correction: The JVM does not know about auto-boxing, this needs to be implemented at runtime. Its all Scala compiler tricks.

Comment: you mean that the autoboxing is actually triggered "manually" in the bytecode. I learned something too :)

Comment: Yes, the JVM has absolutely no notion of boxing or unboxing. This is entirely implemented on the Java language level.

Answer (score 4):

Supplementary to "because of autoboxing", you can observe what magic is used.

`-Xprint:all` will show which compiler phase has done the magic.

`-Ytyper-debug` shows what decisions were made by typer.

For instance, given `val a: Int`, then `val b = a.isInstanceOf[AnyRef]` is changed to `Int.box(a).$asInstanceOf[Object]` in erasure, where `$asInstanceOf` is the nominal member of `Object`.

There's a nice comment about these transforms [in erasure](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/Erasure.scala#L551):

```
/**  Replace member references as follows:
 *
 *   - `x == y` for == in class Any becomes `x equals y` with equals in class Object.
 *   - `x != y` for != in class Any becomes `!(x equals y)` with equals in class Object.
 *   - x.asInstanceOf[T] becomes x.$asInstanceOf[T]
 *   - x.isInstanceOf[T] becomes x.$isInstanceOf[T]
 *   - x.isInstanceOf[ErasedValueType(tref)] becomes x.isInstanceOf[tref.sym.tpe]
 *   - x.m where m is some other member of Any becomes x.m where m is a member of class Object.
 *   - x.m where x has unboxed value type T and m is not a directly translated member of T becomes T.box(x).m
 *   - x.m where x is a reference type and m is a directly translated member of value type T becomes x.TValue().m
 *   - All forms of x.m where x is a boxed type and m is a member of an unboxed class become
 *     x.m where m is the corresponding member of the boxed class.
 */
```

By contrast, the conversion due to the ascription mentioned in the OP's error message happens because of an implicit in `Predef`:

```
scala> val I: java.lang.Integer = a
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // <console>

private[this] val I: Integer = scala.this.Predef.int2Integer($line3.$read.$iw.$iw.a);
```

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of this kind of commands which show compiler outputs/debug? They are very hard to find if you don't know specifically what to look for.

Comment: @EndeNeu `scalac -X` or `scalac -Y`. I think they're hard to find even if you know what to look for.